# Render webgl in requestAnimationFrame got 1 FPS when running for a while

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, requestanimationframe

I try to render webgl animation by requestAnimationFrame.It run in 60fps for a while.Suddenly turn to 1 fps.After 500~1000ms, got 60 FPS again. 
I use three.js to calculate the matrix and program something to render model.Just fell so confused about it.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks for your time.

This is my codepen link.

```
    `https://codepen.io/xiaoshaung/pen/MOgXmN`
```

[image: There is the screenshot for my demo.Just run worse with time.]

Comment: It is problem with your computer, this script works good no my server

Comment: No, I run demo from three.js.It just got smooth. I'll upload a screenshot for my demo.

Comment: The link in your question is not an actual link...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed significant drop once you `focus` or leave the canvas/iframe (click into the area). I think this happens on codepen because of the code is running in the iframe (with cross origin). Is it the drop? You might try to test it out of the iframe on your localhost and share the results here.

Comment: I test it already.I build this demo on localhost.Then i find this issue and paste code on codepen.

Comment: @xiaoshaung well I can only advice to try to isolate the problem. Is it an engine, your code, or some kind of browser bug? Then you could address more viable audience with this question

Comment: Thank you.And i found where my problem is.I use the wrong code to calc matrix. It runs new Float32Array() every time when i build Matrix4.Thanks for your time.Appreciate it.